# What is the use of webservices can anyone explain

Tags: web-services, asp.net-core-webapi

Right now I'm working in WebApi (trainee developer), and have good knowledge in webapi . But , I don't know anything about WebServices.
My Questions are :

1.What is WebServices?
2.What is the Use of WebServices?
3.Instead of WebServices why we are using WebApi.
4.Where we can use WebServices?
5.At a time We Can use both Webservices and WebApis?

Answer (score 0):

**Exposing the Existing Function on the network**

A web service is a unit of managed code that can be remotely invoked using HTTP. That is, it can be activated using HTTP requests. Web services allow you to expose the functionality of your existing code over the network. Once it is exposed on the network, other applications can use the functionality of your program.

**Interoperability**

Web services allow various applications to talk to each other and share data and services among themselves. Other applications can also use the web services. For example, a VB or .NET application can talk to Java web services and vice versa. Web services are used to make the application platform and technology independent.

**Standardized Protocol**

Web services use standardized industry standard protocol for the communication. All the four layers (Service Transport, XML Messaging, Service Description, and Service Discovery layers) use well-defined protocols in the web services protocol stack. This standardization of protocol stack gives the business many advantages such as a wide range of choices, reduction in the cost due to competition, and increase in the quality.

**Low Cost Communication**

Web services use SOAP over HTTP protocol, so you can use your existing low-cost internet for implementing web services. This solution is much less costly compared to proprietary solutions like EDI/B2B. Besides SOAP over HTTP, web services can also be implemented on other reliable transport mechanisms like FTP

**For Example  in Asp.Net Core : https://dzone.com/articles/step-by-step-aspnet-core-restful-web-service-devel**